# how do I save all my texts before I reset it?

Tags: sms

I have an android HTC 660 how do I save all my texts before I reset it? Not for sure how to send to my SIM card

Answer (score 1):

[HoverChat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninja.sms) has an SMS backup feature. It saves all your SMS in a .ninja file, then you can send it in a mail. You must have HoverChat if you want to restore your backup afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked up on the web there's a couple of applications such as :

- SMS Backup+
- G Cloud Backup
- SMS backup restore

Personally,I would take a couple of screenshots and send them into my PC(as backup). Then reset my cell phone and re-transfer my pictures into it.

But if you want them as a txt form, use an application to back up them.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Superbackup](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.idea.backup.smscontacts%26hl%3Den&ei=OJg2VOLGOYOvyASZhYKICA&usg=AFQjCNEY_5pVor08Z1fvteXy3QhZNf9Oag&bvm=bv.76943099,d.aWw) and make backup of contacts , texts and call logs and you can move it local SD card to your inbox.